# @PreAuthorize not working with oauth2 external server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have created separate spring boot oAuth2 separate server and using to secure in the separate REST API project by using the below configuration. Everything is working fine except this TAG  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')"). It not working

**YML Configuration:**
security:
oauth2:
resource:
token-info-uri: http://127.0.0.1:9191/oauth/check_token

[image]

**Controller:**

Note: I also tried with @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')") but nothing happened.
[image]

**AuthorizationServerConfigurer:**
[image]

Comment: what error you are getting after @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('USER')") , please specify

Comment: I have updated my answer after checking your project.

Answer (score 0):

in your `ProfileServiceApplication` it should be
`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` not `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)`

Comment: Added config in resource server, still same.

Comment: add all your configs in your post as what you provided is not enough

Comment: I have uploaded all the code on GitHub repo:                                <br> https://github.com/zahidmx/stackoverflow